# Execute onClick immediately without getting error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal in React JS where I want to execute a function upon opening the modal. This is a button function and it works completely fine so far by having it like so:

```
<button onClick={functionExample("stringParam", true)} id='buttonId' className="buttonClass" />
```

The only issue with this is that it throws this error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
```

Is there any way to do this without getting the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with an arrow function.

`onClick={() => functionExample("stringParam", true)}`

Comment: This is phrased a little misleadingly. It does NOT have to be an arrow function: `onClick={function() { functionExample("stringParam", true) }}` will work just as well. The key point is that a function needs to be passed, not the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a function, which will be later called by React like this:

```html
<button onClick={() => functionExample("stringParam", true)} id='buttonId' className="buttonClass" />
```

When you do JS "stores" the function for later execution, but if you write

```js
onClick={functionExample("stringParam", true)}
```

your code gets execute in place, returns an object and this is what React complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

Your onClick listener is a calling the method on render instead of onClick

```
   <button onClick={() => functionExample("stringParam", true)} id='buttonId' className="buttonClass" />
```

Change your onClick to

```
   onClick={() => functionExample("stringParam", true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you invoked a function which is named "functionExample" then assign the return value of this function to onClick. You have to assign a callback function to "onClick" and inside of that function you need to call "functionExample" function like below.

```
onClick={() => functionExample("stringParam", true)}
```